# Download links php

Tags: php, ftp, download

I'm trying to make an interface where user can log in and download files from a ftp server. I got a problem with my download links, and it only downloads the last file in the list even if i press the first.

Here is my code:

```
    $a = ftp_nlist($conn_id, "/web/images");

foreach($a as $value){
    if ($i <= 1) {
        $i ++;
    }

    else {
echo "<br>";    
echo '<ul><li>'."$value".'</li>';
echo '<li><a href="download.php?="' . $value . '>Download</a></li>';
echo '<li><a href="' . "$value" . '"' . 'target="_blank">Preview</a></li></ul>';
$_SESSION['download'] = $value;

    }
 }

?>
```

And here is download.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$value = $_SESSION['download'];

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($value));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($value));
?>
```

As you can see I'm fairly new to php so any help would be great!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The value of $_SESSION['download']; is always the last file on the FTP connection.
Since you are throwing the path via GET, you should use it instead.

Change

```
$value = $_SESSION['download'];
```

To

```
$value = $_GET['download'];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
echo '<li><a href="download.php?="' . $value . '>Download</a></li>';
```

change this line to this

```
echo '<li><a href="download.php?download="' . $value . '>Download</a></li>';
```

and in the download.php get the value of download like

```
$value = $_GET['download'];
```

Comment: Well now it saves every file as download.php, any way around that one?

Comment: header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($value)); in this line you can change the filename

Comment: I want to keep the original name of the file and download with the correct extension, how do I do that?

Comment: @user2522495 just add file extension basename($value).put_extension_here

Comment: and dont forget to put quotes around filename like this `header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename( $value ).'"' );`